# How change the programme for the doc file?

Tags: windows-7

I have files with .doc extensions. But when I click on them the default browser is opened. When I want to change the program by right click -> open with -> find the MS Office .exe file and click on open, it does not appear in the window so I could not select the program.

How can I do the same thing in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file -> move to Open With -> Click on Choose default program

On the window that opens select the program that you want to use to open the file with.  If Word is not in the list.  Click on the small down arrow that says Other Programs.  If it is not in that list also, you will need to click on browse.  Browse to the Office folder.  It should be in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\  then select WINWORD.exe

This should then open the file in Microsoft Word.

Comment: When I click on WINWORD.exe, it does not appear in Programe List.

Comment: Then will need to browse to your Office folder and manually select the WINWORD.exe

Comment: It does not help!

Answer (score -1):

Isn't there a tick box down the bottom that says "Always Open with this" when you select msoffice.exe ?  (I'm not at work to check)
I would tick that to make sure it always opens it with Ms Office.